# 404 when calling post from resttemplate

Tags: spring

I am attemtping to call a service using rest template and I am receiving a 404 error.

It's a POST. The signature of method is

```
String sendScreenAsPostcard(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, Object> params)
```

I am attenpting to call this from the resttemplate with the following code.

```
restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:8080/sendScreeenAsPostCard",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers),
            String.class
        ).getBody()
```

Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: sendScreeenAsPostCard vs sendScreeenAsPostcard

Answer (score 1):

404 means the resource isn't found. If everything is fairly straightforward, it means there's an HTTP server running at localhost:8080, but no resource available at /sendScreenAsPostCard.